# get checked checkbox count from each div without looping over div

Tags: jquery

let say I have HTML like :

```
<div id="div1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc1" value="v1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc2" value="v2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc3" value="v3" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc4" value="v1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc5" value="v2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc6" value="v3" />
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc7" value="v1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc8" value="v2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dc9" value="v3" />
</div>
```

I want checked check box count from each div, I know I can do this by doing `each` loop on `div` and get the count, but I will surprise if there is way to do this without loop, Is there any?

Comment: do you mean, count how many radio buttons there are inside each div?

Comment: each div can have only one checked radio since all the radios in a div has the same name

Comment: @ArunPJohny I thought the same. I assume OP wants to know if 1 or 0 radios are checked in the group

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I have taken radio button just as example, there can be a checkbox also.

Comment: Why down vote? Is there something wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cd8t6jco/1/)

This will populate count_radios with radios checked:

```
    var count_radios = [];
    $(":raio:checked").each(function(){
        count_radios.push( 
            $(this).closest("div").attr("id") + "-" +
            $(this).val() );
    });
```

Comment: Ohh means I have to loop over `div`, Is it necessary?

Comment: Can I find like,count of  `div` having 0 selected checkbox/radio button without looping?

Comment: I think to select the _:radio_ the DOM is searched recursively, if I'm true then it is impossible don't pass through the divs.